# WSO2 EI: how to handle swedish characters in WSO2 when using vfs to pick csv file

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using vfs transport to pick one csv file and then performing data mapping to it.
This CSV file contains some swedish characters in one of the field like 'Testö'

When the file gets pick up it get changes to Test� and then its get to data mapping to convert into json format and then it remains in this way till the message is sent out to the end consumer.
Is there a way I can handle swedish character in vfs transport as well by setting up encoding to UTF or ISO 8859

I have used

```
<property name="CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" 
value="UTF-8"/>
```

and

```
<property name="CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" 
value="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

but it didnot change the value at all. Can some one please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set transport.vfs.ContentType paramenter of your vfs proxy?
You can include encoding split with a semi-colon character.

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/csv;charset=UTF-8</parameter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I have included charset=ISO-8859-1 and it works.